# Array Vertical order in different columns by alphabet

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
A | B | D | F
A | C | E | G
B | C |
```

I have array of data which:

- **Need to be vertical aligned by alphabet;**
- Need to order array on 4 columns for large screens;
- need to order array on 3 columns for medium screens;
- need to order array on 2 columns for small screens;
- order must be alphabetical;

Example of 3 columns

```
A | C | E
A | C | F
B | D | G
B |
```

**column-count** in CSS is the best for now but working wrong on responsive

I thinking about Vue.js which depending on screen size (can add/remove columns) and move array data between columns

I use bootstrap for HTML

Here code that I did, but it's not enough for work as needed https://codepen.io/alexander-chumak/pen/JvyLPJ

Comment: Possibly dupilicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113999/create-dynamic-html-table-using-javascript-from-simple-array/50114188#50114188

Comment: I don't get the logic. How do you go from `A | B | D | F` to `A | C | E` just by resizing the screen?

Comment: you can use the screen size to determine whether is a small medium or big one and break the td loop like in example it change td after 5

Comment: $(window).width() you can use this function to get the screen size

Comment: What does "working wrong" mean?

Comment: @myself Oh, I get it. These are _vertical_ columns

Comment: guys, please read the title - VERTICAL ALIGNED, not horizotal

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to manage number of td based on size , you can put below code into a function and call this function on window resize event provided by jQuery.  like i did in example

```js
function drawTable(){
    var array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"];
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    var maxWidth = 50;
    var maxColumn = 2;

    if(windowSize < 400){
        maxWidth = 33;
        maxColumn = 3;
    }
    if(windowSize < 800){
        maxWidth = 25;
        maxColumn = 4;
    }
    
    var maxItemInColumn = Math.ceil(array.length/maxColumn);
    
    var result = "<div style='width:100%;'>";
    result += "<ul style='float:left;'>";
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        result += "<li>" + array[j] + "</li>";
        if ((j + 1) % maxItemInColumn === 0) {
            result += "</ul><ul style='float:left;'>";
        }
    }
    result += "</ul>";
    result += "</div>";

    document.body.innerHTML = result;
}
drawTable();
$( window ).resize(function() {
    drawTable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it should vertical aligned! RTL and LTR no problem

Comment: @AleksandrChumak i haved added it as per your need please have a look

Comment: Taylor, good try, almost working, but same bug as with column-count in CSS, 
if in your code to put 6 columns:
3,3,3,3,1,empty elemtns per column
it should be 3,2,2,2,2,2 so all columns have elemts

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Vue  I'd use a computed for the items by column. That way when the items or columnCount changes you don't need to worry about rerunning anything yourself.

You can do something like:

```
data () {
  return {
    columnCount: 2,
    items: [],
  }
},

created () {
  // You should debounce this callback.
  window.addEvenetListener('resize', this.updateColumnCount)
  this.updateColumnCount()
},

destroyed () {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateColumnCount)
},

methods: {
  updateColumnCount () {
    // updat the columnCount here like: this.columnCount = 2
  },
},

computed: {
  itemsByColumn () {
    return this.items.reduce((columns, item, index) => {
      const columnNumber = index % this.columnCount

      if (!columns[columnNumber]) {
        columns[columnNumber] = []
      }

      columns[columnNumber].push(item)

      return columns
    })
  },
},
```

Then, in your template, you can do like:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="column" v-for="(column, index) in itemsByColumn" :key="index">
    <div class="item" v-for="item in column" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is not tested but it should get you mostly there.