# Getting input from user for adding rows in columns from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a freshie in javascript and I am trying to make a table which depends on user input to add rows to a table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>New Cell</td>
                <td>New Cell</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var input = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);
                for (var i = 0 ; i < parseInt(input,10); i++) {
                    var table = document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(i);
                    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i]; j++) {
                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
                        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Take Input from the user using javascript to add rows dynamically

Comment: Answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113999/create-dynamic-html-table-using-javascript-from-simple-array can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Your code is not correct. The insertRow method doesnt return table but it returns a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this:
You can also refer to this like for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var input = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);
            for (var i = 0 ; i < parseInt(input,10); i++) {
                var rowObj = document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(i);
                for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i]; j++) {
                    var cell1 = rowObj.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = rowObj.insertCell(1);
                    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
                    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```